# Google Script to copy formula to Value and only on new data entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet linked to a Google Form, once the form is completed a formula pulls in some weather information from OpenWeatherMap.org. To keep the weather information from that date/time I created a script that copies the formula to a value.

I would like a script that does this, but only runs on new data, leaving previous cells alone.
For example, if A1 copied data to values in B1, and new data from the Form populates A2, then the script would ignore A1&B1 and copy A2 in to B2.

The code below was provided to me, It has two functions, it has not worked how I would like.

```
function moveValuesOnly1() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var srg=sh.getRange(1,2,sh.getLastRow(),6);
  var vA=srg.getValues();
  sh.getRange(getLastRowOfRange("H:M")+1,8,srg.getHeight(),srg.getWidth()).setValues(vA);
}


function getLastRowOfRange(A1Range) {
  var A1Range=A1Range||"H:M";//default for debugging
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(A1Range);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=vA.length-1;i>-1;i--) {
    if(vA[i].join("").length==0) {
      vA.splice(i,1);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(vA.length);
  return vA.length;
}
```

As I mentioned earlier, if A1 copied data to values in B1, and new data from the Form populates A2, then the script would ignore A1&B1 and copy A2 in to B2.

Comment: Do you understand what the first function in your code is doing? It gets from B1 to G  of the last row, copies those values, pastes them in after the last row of H:M with content in it. If I'm understanding what you want, you just want to ignore lines where cells already have content, and only copy ones where those cells are blank. Is that right? It would help if you would share a sample of what a potential sheet may look like--but especially, is A2 in your example *guaranteed* to be the last row, or will there be multiple rows which all need to be copied?

Comment: Hi @Altigraph, thank you for your reply. I have created a different sheet on my google account, as the one I am working on is with work so difficult to share. but this might give you an idea. if the script copied say rows 1-3, when 4-6 is entered it only copies those cells not ones already copied. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fCwx2zQBgjrR0U1JXgHRPefHDOJjtfH9ohJ8H97rsfI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: And in answer to your last part, this would be a forever going spreadsheet, with data being completed all of the time, so there would not ever be a last row. I hope this helps.

Comment: last row in GAS generally means [the last row with data in it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()), it is not a temporal reference. In your spreadsheet there is only "Weather" in row one (is that a header?), row two has values, and 3-6 are formulas. So you are not referring to copied information, but rather values which are not computed by a formula, is that correct?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just use [`getFormula()` or `getFormulas()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormula()) to check if it is a formula and then get/set only those values

Comment: Hi @Altigraph. I am new to script so you may need to spell this out to me. Row 1 is yes just a header for now, row 2 onwards would be populated via a google form and then I add the weather formula's in. So it would be for example row 2-6 as it now, and if a new form was filled in, filling data in to row 7, it would only ignore rows 2-6. Could you help show me what the code might look like?  
  The actual spreadsheet I am working on has the script I showed above, so it copies the formulas as 'Values' in columns H:M. So I want the formula to ignore any rows that already contain data

Comment: Take a look around at other scripts made for working with google sheets, specifically search for scripts containing `getValues()` or `getFormulas()` -- either will show you how to take the two dimensional array those return, make a loop to look at the entries within them, compare their values to what you're looking for, and then act on that data. You might also look up working with two dimensional arrays in regular Javascript. A simplified case would be along the lines of `var f = ...getFormulas(); for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) { if (f[i][0]) { ...getValues() ...setValues() } }`